# Spring Cloud @StreamListener custom error handler

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, apache-kafka, spring-cloud

I'm using Spring Cloud to handle messages from Kafka however I'm looking guidance or example please how to implement an ErrorHandler to log a custom message when listener throws an exception.

Example code below:

```
@EnableBinding(Customer.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public static class CustomerEventListner{

@StreamListener("customerloginEvent")
public void handleCustomerLoginEventListner() {
   // handle the message
}
```

By default if no error handler is definded then defalt Kafka logging is done:

Error message:
 *[afka-listener-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic =*